# Scale SVG Background Image on div when window resizes

Tags: html, css, svg

Looking for some help.
I'm trying to scale an image (.essentials) proportionately  which is set as background in the css and applied to a div.

The image does resize proportionately when the window is made smaller but the problem is that the height to the div is kept the same leaving a huge gap.

I'm using modernizr for fallback to detect if svg is supported to get the svg image and if not to get the png image for IE8 and below.

HTML below

```
<div class="essentials"></div>
```

CSS below

```
.essentials{
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    height: 505px;
}
.svg .essentials{
    background: url("../images/myEssentials.svg") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.no-svg .essentials{
    background: url("../images/myEssentials.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the div has no content, use e.g.

```
padding-bottom: 50%; // 2:1 aspect ratio
```

To add support for IE6 and IE5, include

```
height: 0; // IE6 (hasLayout)
```

(If the div has content, you need an additional wrapper div.  This is all taken from http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video).